# How do I get order nested meta data in WooCommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

We have installed another plugin for WooCommerce called `Booster Plus for WooCommerce` and this plugin can modify the `checkout page` by paying for an order by `invoice number`.

I am customizing our `thank you page` by displaying the `invoice number` too. Currently, I am not able to do that because I don't know how can I properly get the value of the nested `$order->get_data()` result.

```
<?php 
  $order_data = $order->get_data();
  print_r($order_data);
?>
```

The result of `order_data` above looks like below:

```
(
    [id] => 7403
    [discount_total] => 0
    [discount_tax] => 0
    [shipping_total] => 0.00
    [shipping_tax] => 0
    [cart_tax] => 2.47
    [total] => 21.47
    [total_tax] => 2.47
    [customer_id] => 20
    [order_key] => wc_order_8pt3q7T79
    [billing] => Array
    (
      [first_name] => John
      [last_name] => Done
      [company] => g2x
      [address_1] => 3134 James Street
      [address_2] => 
      [city] => Moose Factory
      [state] => ON
      [postcode] => P0L 1W0
      [country] => CA
      [email] => testjohndoe123@gmail.com
      [phone] => 705-658-2112
    )
    [cart_hash] => 087347d19dff4677dc8kaeb2b2c653c6
    [number] => 7403
    [meta_data] => Array
    (
      [0] => WC_Meta_Data Object
        (
          [current_data:protected] => Array
              (
                  [id] => 102652
                  [key] => mailchimp_woocommerce_campaign_id
                  [value] => 
              )

          [data:protected] => Array
              (
                  [id] => 102652
                  [key] => mailchimp_woocommerce_campaign_id
                  [value] => 
              )
        )

      [1] => WC_Meta_Data Object

      [2] => WC_Meta_Data Object

      [3] => WC_Meta_Data Object

      [4] => WC_Meta_Data Object

      [5] => WC_Meta_Data Object
      (
        [current_data:protected] => Array
        (
          [id] => 102694
          [key] => _wcj_custom_payment_gateway_input_fields
          [value] => Array
          (
            [pay_by_po] => 123456789
          )
        )

        [data:protected] => Array
        (
          [id] => 102694
          [key] => _wcj_custom_payment_gateway_input_fields
          [value] => Array
            (
              [pay_by_po] => 123456789
            )
        )
      )
    [coupon_lines] => Array
    ()

)
```

Do you know how can I get the value of `[pay_by_po]` which is `123456789`? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get and unprotect this nested meta data using [`WC_data` method `get_meta_data()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html), which gives an array of [`WC_Meta_Data`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Meta_Data.html) Objects:

```
$meta_data = $order->get_meta_data();
print_r($order_data);
```

Then on each `WC_Meta_Data` Object, you can use [`WC_Meta_Data` available methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Meta_Data.html) like `get_data()` that gives an unprotected data array:

```
foreach( $order->get_meta_data() as $meta_data_obj ) {
    $meta_data_array = $meta_data_obj->get_data();
    print_r($meta_data_array);

    $meta_key   = $meta_data_array['key']; // The meta key
    $meta_value = $meta_data_array['value']; // The meta value
}
```

You can also get directly any nested meta data from the order using [`WC_Data` method `get_meta()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html#_get_meta) from aspecific meta key as follow:

```
$meta_value = $order->get_meta('_wcj_custom_payment_gateway_input_fields');
print_r($meta_value);
```

> Note This nested meta data exist since WooCommerce version 3.

---

#### About Abstract `WC_Data` Class

Its Implemented by classes using the same CRUD(s) pattern.

**Direct known subclasses:** 
`WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order`, `WC_Abstract_Legacy_Product`, `WC_Customer_Download`, `WC_Customer_Download_Log`, `WC_Legacy_Coupon`, `WC_Legacy_Customer`, `WC_Legacy_Payment_Token`, `WC_Legacy_Shipping_Zone`, `WC_Legacy_Webhook`, `WC_Order_Item`

**Indirect known subclasses:** 
`WC_Abstract_Order`, `WC_Coupon`, `WC_Payment_Token`, `WC_Payment_Token_CC`, `WC_Payment_Token_ECheck`, `WC_Product`, `WC_Product_External`, `WC_Product_Grouped`, `WC_Product_Simple`, `WC_Product_Variable`, `WC_Product_Variation`, `WC_Shipping_Zone`, `WC_Customer`, `WC_Webhook`, `WC_Order`, `WC_Order_Item_Coupon`, `WC_Order_Item_Fee`, `WC_Order_Item_Product`, `WC_Order_Item_Shipping`, `WC_Order_Item_Tax`, `WC_Order_Refund`

See: [Developing using WooCommerce CRUD objects](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/developing-using-woocommerce-crud-objects/)

Comment: There's a typo resulting in a fatal error in the second code block, "meta_data_obj" should be "$meta_data_obj", I can't edit the post because edits must be at least 6 characters long, so I'm commenting here.